# How to install the right-click photo-resizer on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, ubuntu-mate, photo

I would really like to install the nautilus **right click photo re-sizer** in my Ubuntu Mate 18.04.  I had it in UM 16.04 and have been trying without success to get it to show up in 18.04.

Thanks for all the help...

Answer (score 10):

## How to Install Resize Images with Right Click

This instruction follows this [tip](https://itsfoss.com/resize-images-with-right-click/).

First verify that you have nautilus as file manager:

```
nautilus --version
```

The output should be something like **Gnome nautilus 3.26.3**

Second install ImageMagick

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

Then simple install the nautilus-image-converter

```
sudo apt install nautilus-image-converter
```

When installation has completed, restart nautilus by using the command

```
nautilus -q
```

Open nautilus and right click on an image file. Select **Resize Images ...** and a window should open like the on below.

[image]

To uninstall simple type

```
sudo apt remove nautilus-image-converter
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 but this [article](https://itsfoss.com/resize-images-with-right-click/) describes Right Click setup. To summarize:

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
sudo apt install nautilus-image-converter
nautilus -q # Reloads nautilus configuration
```

Watch the screen carefully for error messages that may appear under Ubuntu Mate 18.04. There were no errors in Ubuntu 16.04 and two new options appear on the right click Nautilus menu:

- Resize images...
- Rotate images...

Resizing an image appears to work perfectly.

Comment: I have caja file manager.  Replace Natulas with Caja and all is good again...